# Nest js upload is not saving file

Tags: nestjs, multer

I'm following the `nestjs` documentation for [File upload](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload), my endpoint is getting the file, but the file is not stored.

I'm using the same configuration than NesJS

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

My `app.module` file, I added the import for:

```
MulterModule.register({
      dest: './uploads'
    })
```

But the file is not stored in the directory `uploads`. The complete log is:

```
undefined
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'nopornimage.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 04 d00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 04 ... 20087 more bytes>,
  size: 20137
}
```

(Yes, including the `undefined`)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should specify the destination. [multer options](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts)

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {
  dest: 'uploads/'
}))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

or you can use [createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) in `fs` module to save file by yourself.

```js
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs'

@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
  const ws = createWriteStream('custom_filename')
  ws.write(file.buffer)
  console.log(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you should register `multer` module in your domain module not in app
   module(unless  app module is the only module in your project ) for
   example if your controller belongs to task domain  you should
   register `multer` in task module not in app module

```
   imports: [
     TypeOrmModule.forFeature([TaskRepository]),
     MulterModule.register({ dest: './upload' }),
   ],
   controllers: [TaskController],
   providers: [TaskService],
 })
 export class TaskModule {}
```

2. create `upload` directory and  determine it's path in `multer`
   registration

Comment: The problem here is that MulterModule is not a global module. So we need to add it to the imports array of the module where we are doing the upload. I think the NestJS documentation should highlight this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file', {dest: 'uploads/'}))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
    console.log(file);
}
```

You can use 'dest' keyword with decortor

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2374) and Paolo mentioned, `MulterModule` is intentionally designed to be used as a feature module, your behavior can be achieved either using the `@Global` decorator, configuring it using `forRoot`, or re-exporting the module.

I would suggest the latest, in my case I tend to use a `FileStorageModule` to encapsulate all this logic, including metadata storage services, url transform controllers, etc.